# Unable to replace data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file named data.txt, just like this:

```
 1248 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face serious) (_prop '())
 1249 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face funny) (_prop '())
 1250 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face serious) (_prop '())
 1251 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face serious) (_prop '())
 1252 (_sex  female) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face smiling) (_prop '())
 1253 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face serious) (_prop '())
 1254 (_sex  male) (_age  child) (_race white) (_face serious) (_prop '())
```

And I use re to match the data and save them to numpy.

When I try to change data in ndarray, I find it cannot be changed，just like this:

```py
import re
import numpy as np

dataSet = 'data.txt'
tagData = []

with open(dataSet, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.findall(r"(\d+)|\b_missing.descriptor|\b_(?:sex|age|[rf]ace)\s+(\w+)|_prop..\(([^()]*).\)\)",
                           line)
        labelList = np.array(["".join(x) for x in match])
        if labelList[4] == 'funny': # repalce 'funny' to 'smiling'
            labelList[4] = 'smiling'
        tagData.append(labelList)
```

The `tagData[1]` should be `['1249' 'male' 'child' 'white' 'smiling']`,
but it is `['1249' 'male' 'child' 'white' 'smili']`, missing `'ng'`.

Numpy version is 1.19.2, Python version is 3.8.8.

Comment: I've got exactly what you're expected from your code. I don't know what's the issue on your output. You may check whether it's a display issue.

Comment: @MaheryRanaivoson Thanks，I use labelList = np.char.replace(labelList, 'funny', 'smiling') to repalce， and I get the answer :)

Comment: In your own words, why are you using Numpy for this task? How are you hoping it will help you? (The problem occurs because the data type that Numpy infers for your array, allocates exactly enough space for the already-existing string data. Incidentally, that array only has one element in it, of a structure type that Numpy creates on the fly. The entire point of using Numpy is to have it store all the rows at once, not to loop and create a new array for each row.)